# NPM watch error: ReferenceError: _ is not defined at ../node_modules/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js (angular-google-maps.js:1:1)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-google-maps

I'm using Angular and I've restarted mycomputer and in the browser at the console section appeared to me an error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: _ is not defined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ReferenceError: _ is not defined at ../node_modules/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js (angular-google-maps.js:1:1)
```

I reinstalled **node-modules**, but still nothing, on the *github* there is an issue:
https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/issues/1932

But still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete **node-modules** folder
2. Update your **npm** and **node**:
   https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm and
   https://nodejs.org/en/download
3. Then do `npm cache clean --force`
4. Run `npm ci`
5. Rerun the `watch`

If still doesn't work, then after 2nd step do the following:

```
npm uninstall angular-google-maps

npm install @agm/core --legacy-peer-deps
```